# GAS: jmp to label results in wrong jump?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I am trying to assembly following program:

```
    .text
.globl _search2
_search2:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
go_again:
    cmpl    $0x90909090, (%rax)
    je  go_out
    addq    $0x8, %rax
    jmp     go_again
go_out: 
    leave
    ret
```

by doing this: "gcc -o test test.s main.c" and I get this:

otool -v -t test

```
_search2:
0000000100000d0c    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000d0d    movq    %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000d10    movq    %rax,0xf8(%rbp)
go_again:
0000000100000d14    cmpl    $0x90909090,(%rax)
0000000100000d1a    je  0x100000d29
0000000100000d20    addq    $0x08,%rax
0000000100000d24    jmp 0x200000d14
go_out:
0000000100000d29    leave
0000000100000d2a    ret
```

The jmp is trying to jump to address 0x200000d14 which is totally wrong instead of 0x100000d29 which is marked with go_out label.

Please help.

Comment: @Mat No, the `jmp go_again` should be `jmp 0x100000d14`. It is getting an extra 0x100000000 somewhere. `@user476173, could you provide raw object code along with the disassembly?

Comment: `jmp` goes to `go_again` = `0000000100000d14` and `je` goes to `go_out` = `0000000100000d29` . What is the problem?

Comment: @phoxis, the `jmp` is going to `0x200000d14` rather than `0x100000d14` (2, not 1).

Comment: as search2.s -o search2.o

otool -v -t search2.o


search2.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_search2:
0000000000000000 pushq %rbp
0000000000000001 movq %rsp,%rbp
0000000000000004 movq %rax,0xf8(%rbp)
go_again:
0000000000000008 cmpl $0x90909090,(%rax)
000000000000000e je 0x00000014
0000000000000014 addq $0x08,%rax
0000000000000018 jmp 0x100000008
go_out:
000000000000001d leave

Comment: Looks like absolute vs. relative addressing for je and jmp. How to specify correct one?

Comment: @user476173: you are right, sorry i overlooked it.

Comment: It looks like the offset of the jmp is signed 32-bit. It adds the offset to the lower 32 bits of the address, which generates a carry so it increments the upper 32 bits. As the offset is signed and the MSB is set, it's negative, so that shouldn't happen. You just need to check that it's only the tool displaying it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try objdump -D test > test.list

```
00000000004004c4 <_search2>:
  4004c4:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004c5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004c8:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)

00000000004004cc <go_again>:
  4004cc:   81 38 90 90 90 90       cmpl   $0x90909090,(%rax)
  4004d2:   74 06                   je     4004da <go_out>
  4004d4:   48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax
  4004d8:   eb f2                   jmp    4004cc <go_again>

00000000004004da <go_out>:
  4004da:   c9                      leaveq 
  4004db:   c3                      retq
```

See if the tool you are using can display the instructions, if the instructions are the (somewhat the) same then the relative address is correct and you can ignore the address the tool is displaying, or just not use that tool.

If the branches are direct and dont match the target, then there is a gcc/gnu tools problem.